# What isJiva and jivatma ? what is the co- relationship between the two in accordance with the tenets of Advait vedant

Tags: vedanta, advaita, jiva

I have been going through a lot of mention, discussion, opinion on the subject of my question ( Jiva and jivatma and their co- relationship) . Varied terms and terminology has been very liberally used sometimes causing confusion also ( may be on account of my own lack of conviction). It may be because of relevant information having been gathered  from cross section of Vedantic thoughts. My humble request woud be to discuss the subject under question, as far as possible under the ambit of advait vedant.

Comment: Jiva is same as Jivatma, that is an atma bound with mind, body and senses, God or Paramatma is master of Prakriti i.e. mind. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voVqtrOoSuI The passage from being servant of one's mind to be its master eventually is the yoga.

Comment: @ Srimamannarayan sv  your blessings pl.